# Location of the extrema of the sinc function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) provides the following expression for the location of the extrema of the sinc function:

$$x_n=q-q^{-1}-\dfrac{2q^{-3}}{3}-\dfrac{13q^{-5}}{15}-\dfrac{146q^{-7}}{105}...$$

with $q =\left(n + \dfrac 12\right)\pi$

However, I have not been able to find this expression in the literature. Can anyone please provide some references where this expansion is derived, or at least mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [some proceedings](http://sections.maa.org/iowa/db/index.php/proposal/viewPublic/144) from a [2006 MAA chapter meeting](http://sections.maa.org/iowa/db/index.php/proposal/viewPublic/144), the asymptotic expansion for the roots of $$\tan x=x$$ was independently produced by Euler ([1748](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_ryM0Kh6yLkwC), pp 318–320), Cauchy (1827, pp 277–278 in his [complete works](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k90181x/f288.image)), and Rayleigh ([1877](https://archive.org/details/theorysound06raylgoog), pp 278—279).

- Cauchy, Augustin–Louis (1827). Théorie de la Propagation des Ondes à la Surface d’un Fluide Pesant d’une Profondeur Indéfinie.
- Euler, Leonhard (1748). Introductio in Analysin Infinitorum: Tomus Segundus.
- Rayleigh, John William Strutt (1877). The Theory of Sound: Volume 1. Macmillan.